# Second order partial differentials problem

Tags: partial-derivative

I've been given the following:

$$
\begin{cases}
z = \ln(x + y^2)\\
x = t + 1/s\\
y = t
\end{cases}
$$

and have been asked to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}$, and $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s \partial t}$.

I've calculated that:

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{1 + 2t}{t + 1/s + t^2}
$$

and that

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} = -\frac{1}{s^2(t + 1/s + t^2)}
$$

This is fine and matches the mark scheme I've been given. However I cannot seem to work out $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s \partial t}$. I was under the impression that:

$$
\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s \partial t} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}
$$

Is that wrong? And if so what is the correct way of calculating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial s\partial t}$ means:
$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\right)$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial s\partial t}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{1+2t}{t+1/s+t^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial s}(1+2t)\right](t+1/s+t^2)-(1+2t)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial s}(t+1/s+t^2)\right]}{(t+1/s+t^2)^2}\\
&=\frac{(0)(t+1/s+t^2)-(1+2t)\left(-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)}{(t+1/s+t^2)^2}\\
&=\frac{1+2t}{\left[1+s(t+t^2)\right]^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be (2t + 1)/(st(t + 1) + 1)^2

Comment: @GeorgeBaker Yes, you are right. I have corrected the post!